# Activate short codes for all post queries?

Tags: filters, shortcode

I need to use shortcodes on widgets and various plugins. For widgets I simply used:

```
add_filter('widget_title', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

However I cannot figure out how to activate shortcodes for plugins. I noticed all of them get posts with WP_Query and then $post->post_content. Maybe there is a way to filter post queries? How can I activate shortcodes for all post echoes?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to apply that to all post content.

```
function sc_all_content_wpse_137734($posts) {

  foreach ($posts as &$p) {
    $p->post_content = do_shortcode($p->post_content);
  }

  return $posts;
}
add_filter('the_posts','sc_all_content_wpse_137734');
```

I would suggest that this is a very, very good way to break things. Plugins and themes will not expect shortcodes to be rendered that early, and the code above will break shortcodes that depend on the `$post` `global`, though that could be gotten around with `setup_postdata`.